# Input field uppercase while typing react hook form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I add a logic to an old project that use react-hook-form v.3
Long story short, when the user types in the input field, the letters must be uppercase.

This is the code for the input I need to change:

```
// outside the form

const [value, setValue] = useState(data.taxCode ?? '')

const changeHandler = ({ target }) => {
  setValue(target.value.toUpperCase())
}


// inside the form

               <input
                  type='text'
                  name='taxCode'
                  value={value}
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                  ref={register({
                    pattern: {
                      value: taxCodeRgx,
                      message: 'error message,
                    },
                  })}
                />
```

And it works. I have one small problem:
if I double click in the input field and select a previously entered code, it does not select it .. on the second attempt yes.
Also when I type, first character is missing
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I need to set the mode to "onChange": `const methods = useForm({ mode: 'onChange' })`